# ModelState is Invalid for Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

I have a parent table called "Language" which stores the language skills of a person (like he is fluent, good, ok...)

I have a child table "Manpower" with 2 foreign keys pointing to the same table for different languages (English & Arabic).

Now when I try to create a new manpower resource it always return ModelState is invalid for the language.

Error is **"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'AlTmaizMVC3.Models.Language' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."**

Controller :

```
   [Authorize]        
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories.OrderBy(r => r.Name), "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.CountryId = new SelectList(db.Countries.OrderBy(r => r.Name), "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.MaritalStatusId = new SelectList(db.MaritalStatus.OrderBy(r => r.Name), "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.ReligionId = new SelectList(db.Religions.OrderBy(r => r.Name), "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.EnglishID = new SelectList(db.Languages , "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.ArabicID = new SelectList(db.Languages, "Id", "Name");
        return View("~/Views/en/Create.cshtml");
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create(Manpower manpower)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            manpower.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
            manpower.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            db.Manpowers.AddObject(manpower);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("AddImage", new { manpower.Id});  
        }

        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories.OrderBy(r => r.Name), "Id", "Name", manpower.CategoryId);
        ViewBag.CountryId = new SelectList(db.Countries.OrderBy(r => r.Name), "Id", "Name", manpower.CountryId);
        ViewBag.MaritalStatusId = new SelectList(db.MaritalStatus.OrderBy(r => r.Name), "Id", "Name", manpower.MaritalStatusId);
        ViewBag.ReligionId = new SelectList(db.Religions.OrderBy(r => r.Name), "Id", "Name", manpower.ReligionId);
        ViewBag.EnglishID = new SelectList(db.Languages, "Id", "Name", manpower.EnglishID);
        ViewBag.ArabicID = new SelectList(db.Languages, "Id", "Name", manpower.ArabicID);
        return View("~/Views/en/Create.cshtml", manpower);
    }
```

View

```
   <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaritalStatusId, "Marital Status")</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("MaritalStatusId", String.Empty)<br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaritalStatusId)</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnglishID, "English")</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("EnglishID", String.Empty)<br />                    
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnglishID)</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArabicID, "Arabic")</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("ArabicID", String.Empty)<br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArabicID)</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
```

Model for Language table

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="AlTmaizDBModel", Name="Language")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class Language : EntityObject
{
    #region Factory Method

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new Language object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Initial value of the Id property.</param>
    public static Language CreateLanguage(global::System.Int16 id)
    {
        Language language = new Language();
        language.Id = id;
        return language;
    }

    #endregion
    #region Primitive Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int16 Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Id != value)
            {
                OnIdChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Id");
                _Id = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Id");
                OnIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int16 _Id;
    partial void OnIdChanging(global::System.Int16 value);
    partial void OnIdChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            OnNameChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Name");
            _Name = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Name");
            OnNameChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _Name;
    partial void OnNameChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnNameChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String NameAR
    {
        get
        {
            return _NameAR;
        }
        set
        {
            OnNameARChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("NameAR");
            _NameAR = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            ReportPropertyChanged("NameAR");
            OnNameARChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _NameAR;
    partial void OnNameARChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnNameARChanged();

    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("AlTmaizDBModel", "FK_Manpower_Language", "Manpower")]
    public EntityCollection<Manpower> Manpowers
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<Manpower>("AlTmaizDBModel.FK_Manpower_Language", "Manpower");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<Manpower>("AlTmaizDBModel.FK_Manpower_Language", "Manpower", value);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("AlTmaizDBModel", "FK_Manpower_Language1", "Manpower")]
    public EntityCollection<Manpower> Manpowers1
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<Manpower>("AlTmaizDBModel.FK_Manpower_Language1", "Manpower");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<Manpower>("AlTmaizDBModel.FK_Manpower_Language1", "Manpower", value);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: The **M** in `MVC` stands for **Model** and not for `ViewBag`!

Comment: @gdoron I too feel its something to do with the ViewBag. Can you please explain that a lil bit more.

Comment: @Saqib Vaid - The error has nothing to do with the ViewBag.  His comment was to do with your overuse of the ViewBag property rather than using a model (hence **M** in MVC) to pass the information to the view.  You should definitely look over mattytommo's answer below and consider using view models to pass information to your views and not domain/entity models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using a `Model`, not the `ViewBag`, that's where your headache starts!

First let's create a model based on what you need:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Manpower Manpower { get; set; }

    public SelectList Categories { get; set; }
    public SelectList MaritalStatuses { get; set; }
    public SelectList Religions { get; set; }
    public SelectList Languages { get; set; }

    //here's your Load Method to populate it
    public MyModel Load()
    {
        //load your Manpower object here
        Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .ToList(), "Id", "Name");
        Countries = new SelectList(db.Countries
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .ToList(), "Id", "Name");
        MaritalStatuses = new SelectList(db.MaritalStatus
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .ToList(), "Id", "Name");
        Religions = new SelectList(db.Religions
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .ToList(), "Id", "Name");
        Languages = .new SelectList(db.Languages
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .ToList(), "Id", "Name");
    }
}
```

Now let's fix that get controller method:

```
[Authorize]        
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new MyModel().Load();

    return View("~/Views/en/Create.cshtml", model);
}
```

Next, I'll show you **sample** view Code (format it appropriately), note that I'm assuming here that Manpower has all the possible fields:

```
@model MyModel //make sure this is the top line of your view

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Manpower.CategoryId, m.Categories)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Manpower.MaritalStatusId, m.MaritalStatuses)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Manpower.ReligionId, m.Religions)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Manpower.EnglishId, m.Languages)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Manpower.ArabicId, m.Languages)

//your other Manpower object items here now....
```

Now in the Save method we can do:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.Manpower.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
        model.Manpower.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        db.Manpowers.AddObject(model.Manpower);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("AddImage", new { manpower.Id});  
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Create"); //not sure why you're going back to create though?
}
```

Comment: Dude where is the `ViewBag` ...? **+1**

Comment: @gdoron Dude what does mine say? "ViewBag", what does mine say? "Model" DUUUUUDE :D

Comment: @mattytommo I am trying to use your answer, I get an error on View _Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' because it is not a delegate type_ on line @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Manpower.CategoryId, Model.Categories)

Comment: @SaqibVaid I've edited my answer and updated the model, use that code instead and it should work for you :)